# Unix: как происходит инициализация переменных окружения при запуске shell-а?

Tags: linux, unix, shell

Как это происходит? Откуда берутся строчки `var=val`? Откуда `char** environ`? Что происходит при инициализации shell?

Можно просто ответить: "Из системных файлов конфигурации". Я спрошу: "Из каких?" В `/etc/profile` определены лишь некоторые из них, как и в `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.bashrc` (`~/.kshrc`, `~/.zshrc`). Оболочка сама определяет значение переменных, исходя из настроек системы? К примеру, делает вызов `ulimit`, `locale` и прочие, а `USER`, `HOME`, `etc` парсятся из `/etc/passwd`. Эти догадки верны?

Аспекты работы оболочки для меня не совсем очевидны, из мануалов интересующую информацию вычитать не удалось, как и узнать у google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Окружение - неотъемлемая часть всех процессов Unix и как известно, окружение наследуется от вызывающего процесса всеми его потомками. Потомки могут что то поменять в своей копии окружения, добавить, удалить и запустить своих потомков передав им свое, измененное окружение. Поэтому что бы понять, что формирует окружение любого запущенного процесса цепочку запуска надо рассмотреть с самого начала.

И так, Unix система начинает запуск. Загружается ядро. Ядро стартует "процесс номер 1", обычно `/sbin/init`. А уже init стартует  все остальные процессы в системе (см. `/etc/inittab`). Смотрим исходный код `/sbin/init` (на примере sysVinit, который используется linux). Сразу находится функция `init_buildenv` - она создает первоначальное окружение для всех процессов в системе.

```
Окружение формируемое /sbin/init:
RUNLEVEL
PREVLEVEL
SHELL=/bin/sh
CONSOLE
INIT_VERSION
```

Далее init запускает стартер системы (для linux обычно /sbin/rc), который выполняет загрузку демонов, он формирует начальное окружение с которым работают  демоны. Кроме того init стартует поддержку терминалов (в linux обычно agetty), который ставит переменную `TERM`. Для сетевых подключений TERM по идее должен поставить sshd или другое средство подключения. Те в свою очередь запускают /bin/login или сами выполняют его работу. Вот он, авторизовав пользователя, смотрит /etc/passwd и формирует начальное окружение данного пользователя (добавляет к тому, что сделал init):

```
Окружение формируемое /bin/login
HOME
SHELL
USER
LOGNAME
LANG
TZ
HZ
PATH (см. /etc/login.defs)
MAIL (см. /etc/login.defs)
если в /etc/login.defs указан ENVIRONFILE - то добавляется его содержимое
```

Наконец login запускает shell определенный для данного пользователя. Разных shell довольно много и каждый по своему работает с окружением. От себя лично они    добавляют мало, зато львиную долю окружения читают из файлов. Надо смотреть исходники каждого shell, что бы понять, кто что грузит. Для zsh примерный перечень такой:

```
/etc/profile
~/.profile ИЛИ /etc/suid_profile (проверяет привилегии)
/etc/zshenv (если включен при сборке zsh)
~/.zshenv
/etc/zprofile (если включен при сборке zsh)
/etc/zshrc (если включен при сборке zsh)
~/.zshrc
/etc/zlogin (если включен при сборке zsh)
~/.zlogin
```

Кроме того в окружение что то могут добавлять другие процессы, используемые при входе пользователя. `sshd` добавляет свои переменные, модули PAM, используемые при авторизации так же могут это делать.

Comment: То есть нет отдельного хранилища EV. Структура хранится у процесса, который затем передаёт её процессам, которые уже сами изменяют или дополняют её по мере надобности. В данном случае иерархия наследования этой самой структурки (массив строк, выходит) идёт от процесса init; запущенные ей процессы сами ставят для себя всё, что необходимо, при это изменения видны только им и их потомкам. Так выходит?

Comment: @marar, *видны только им и их потомкам* — нет, при наличии достаточных прав в унаследованное окружение процесса может «заглянуть» любой «интересующийся» процесс. пример «заглядывания» — в моём ответе.

Comment: Это и делает getenv? Смотрит в /proc/.../environ?

Comment: getenv смотрит прямо в оперативной памяти, в структуру окружения текущего процесса.

Answer (score 3):

> Откуда берутся строчки var=val?

очевидно, оттуда, где эти строки записаны.

> Откуда char** environ?

переменные окружения? они наследуются процессом-потомком от процесса-родителя. в операционных системах, использующих программу *linux* в качестве ядра, можно увидеть переменные окружения любого процесса в псевдо-файловой системе `/proc`, в файле `/proc/идентификатор-процесса/environ`. так как строки разделены там «нулевыми» символами, удобно просматривать их, например, так:

```
$ cat /proc/идентификато-процесса/environ | xargs -0n 1 echo
```

---

> Что происходит при инициализации shell?

вероятно, то же, что и при инициализации любой другой программы.

> "Из каких?"

из тех, что указали авторы, затем сборщики, затем настройщики программы. ведь в подгружаемом конфигурационном файле можно указать и другие конфигурационные файлы.

> Эти догадки верны?

принадлежность процесса — это одно из его свойств. набор символов, закреплённый за пользователем в качестве его «имени», можно прочитать из `/etc/passwd`. оттуда же можно прочитать, в том числе, и «домашний» каталог пользователя.

Comment: > очевидно, оттуда, где эти строки записаны.
Где именно?

Comment: @marar, вообще — они записаны в оперативной памяти процесса. а поступает информация в подобные структуры, большей частью, от процессов-предков (наследуется).